# Get class pointer name from within its method?

Tags: c++, methods

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to programming and my terminology may be way off. When I say "class pointer name", I mean the "A" in "myClass A" and in "A.Fill(...)".
I'm not sure how to formulate my question to make it as clear as possible, but let me try:

```
class myClass{
public:
    // stuff
    Fill(string msg)
    {
        // does stuff
        cout << msg + "some extra text"; /*here I want to somehow get the name of the class pointer
                which was used when calling this method, rather than having to manually pass it on as a string.*/
        // more stuff
    }
};

int main()
{
    myClass A;
    myClass B;
    myClass C;
    A.Fill("A");
    B.Fill("B");
    C.Fill("C");
}
```

This code is currently doing exactly what I want. However, I am wondering if it's possible to somehow get the class pointer name from within the method, rather than having to manually pass on a string argument every time?
I know that in macros I can use #A #B #C to get exactly that, but I'm uncertain how this would be applied for my code, and if it's possible at all.

Comment: No, you cannot get the *variable name* from within a class function. They are not preserved for use at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t want variable names, and you don’t want to be passing them in each time you call a method of the object.

You want object names. You need to give the `A` object a name, and then this name can be used by all of its methods.

Then, if you want convenience, instead of instantiating it as `ClassA A("A");`, you can have a macro that does it, like

```
#define ClassA_instance(var) ClassA var(#var)
```

Use:

```
ClassA_instance(A);
```

This way, you create an instance of that class that has the same name as the variable - but that’s pure convenience. You will find, soon enough, that you can give objects better names than what suffices for a variable name, especially if those objects are stored inside of other objects, where member variable names may be unwieldy due to eg. the `m_` prefix. You can then also combine object names, so that object B inside of some object A will have its name set to “A.B” or similar. Tying the name to the name of a variable will have very limited uses.

ClassA has to store its name of course, and its constructor must accept the name. Eg.:

```
ClassA {
  std::string m_objectName;
public:
  ClassA(const std::string &name) : m_name(name) {}
  ClassA(const char *name) : m_name(name) {}
  ...
};
```

You could factor out the naming aspect into a base class, although there’s so little code to it that I don’t see the sense in doing it - not unless you have other, better reasons to have a common base class.

Answer (score 0):

Not even the compiler knows what variable name was used to call a member function.  But you're right, you can use a macro to do what you want.

```
#define FILL(X) X.Fill(#X)

FILL(A);
FILL(B);
FILL(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to get a variable name automatically from with a class's function.

To do what you're asking for, it would have to be passed in.

```
Fill(string name, string msg)
{
    //...
}
```

Perhaps you could come up with a macro that could be used in places where the function call is made that would streamline passing in the name.

```
myClass A;
CALLFUNCTIONANDPASSNAME(A, Fill("A"));
```

But in my option that just adds complexity for little value.

Furthermore there are lots of situation where trying to determine the variable name is going to be surprising or unhelpful. For instance:

```
myClass* p = new myClass[2];
p->Fill("...");
++p;
p->Fill("...");
```

Here `Fill` is called on two different instances, but the name of both would be "p". (Disregard the fact that this example does not show good memory management practices. I'm keeping it simple to only show what's relevant to this question.)

---

The better recommendation for class instances to have a name is to treat that as any other data you want a class to have - carry it in a member variable.

```
class myClass
{
    string Name;

    public:

    myClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        cout << "My name is " << Name;
    }
}
```

And then construct your instances with the desired name.

```
myClass fred("Fred");
```